# Including a date or other variable in the git commit message

Tags: git, bash

I need to include the date and time in all commit messages (this is for syncing with a project management tool). I currently have have the alias:

```
alias commitDate = "date +%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M"
```

Is there anyway to include this or any other variables in the commit message?

Comment: Look at the git hooks [prepare-commit-msg](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#_prepare_commit_msg) and [commit-msg](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#_commit_msg)

Comment: You may have no control over the management tool, but if you do, it might be better to convince the tool to extract the author and/or committer date from the commit itself. Of course then you have to decide which of these is relevant.

Comment: Commit date is already present as a separate header field (as is authorship date). Why would you want a duplicate copy?

Answer (score 6):

You can specify the commit message on the command line directly via [`-m` option](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit#git-commit--mltmsggt). So if you want to commit new changes you could type:

```
git commit -m "Your message" -m "`$commitDate`"
```

which would lead to following commit message, as your shell replaces the env var `commitDate` with its value:

```
Your message
*current date*
```

Comment: Is it possible to use env vars in the commit message?

Comment: @Kex Every env var you could use with other bash commands (like `echo`) are  also available in the git command (in terminal, not in IDE).

Comment: @kex your shell expands the envvar before passing it to `git`

Comment: This syntax does not appear to parse "`$commitDate`" if `commitDate` is a local variable in bash.

Answer (score 3):

Using an environment variable:

```
$ export COMMIT_TITLE=$(date)
$ git add commitfile.txt
$ git commit -m "$COMMIT_TITLE"
[master b5a9354] Sun, May 10, 2020  9:38:12 AM
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 commitfile.txt
```